# get handle from process

Tags: process, handle, winapi

how can access to main window handle from process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an article in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/getprocessid.aspx) that retrieves a Windows Handle from a Process name  or by Process Id (in [CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=353149))